# Facebook Graph Api error "An unexpected error has occurred. Please retry your request later"

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I'm trying to retrieve all members in a Facebook group getting this error:

```
 array(5) {
    ["message"]=>
    string(66) "An unexpected error has occurred. Please retry your request later."
    ["type"]=>
    string(14) "OAuthException"
    ["is_transient"]=>
    bool(true)
    ["code"]=>
    int(2)
    ["fbtrace_id"]=>
    string(11) "AnfsXcdgM"
  }
```

Here is my code:

```
$this->_facebook = new Facebook\Facebook(array('app_id' => "$app_id",'app_secret' => "$secret",'default_graph_version' => 'v2.10'));

$this->_facebook->setDefaultAccessToken($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);

$query = "/".$groupID."/members?fields=id,name,link,picture,first_name,last_name";

try{
    $response = $this->_facebook->get($query);
    while($pagesEdge)
    {
     $pageDecoded = json_decode($pagesEdge);
     foreach($pageDecoded as $key => $member)
     {
         $id = $member->id;
     } 
    }
}catch (Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {  echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage(); }
```

It works for groups with few hundreads of people (even once for a group with 10.000 members) but randomly I'm occurring to this.

Comment: are you admin of the group? is it a public group?

Comment: I've tried with every king of user permission and group type. The only problem I have is with huge amount of data..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be caused by a server side timeout. I get this error every now and then when I request a huge amount of data. Maybe you should try to limit your request by using the limit parameter (default should be 25).

Comment: Yeah trying to import a large amount of data I'm getting constantly "Internal Server Error".. After getting 25 fields at time and loop them I am still getting the same error .-.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by doing a cron that takes 100 data at the time and putting into a file text the value of the token for the next call.

I add this string on the query and when the fields inside $url are empty I quit my execution

```
<?php 

public function updateGroupMembers($groupID)
{
    $tempNext = file_get_contents($this->dirM); //check if the next string token is in the file
    if (!empty($tempNext)) 
    {
        $queryUntil = $tempNext;
    }
    // Sets the default fallback access token so we don't have to pass it to each request
    $this->_facebook->setDefaultAccessToken($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);
    // Create table name
    $tableName = $groupID . "_Members";

    // Query the Graph API to get all current member's ID and name
    try 
    {
        $query = "/".$groupID."/members?fields=id,name,link,picture,first_name,last_name".$queryUntil; //add the next string to my query
        $response = $this->_facebook->get($query); 
        $pagesEdge = $response->getGraphEdge();    
        // Index for the elements fetched from the API below
        $i = 0;
        // Get current time
        $pageDecoded = json_decode($pagesEdge);
        foreach($pageDecoded as $key => $member)
        {
           /* ...get data and process them... */
        }   

        $temp = $pagesEdge->getMetaData();
        $next = parse_url($temp['paging']['next']);
        parse_str($next['query'], $url);

        $access_token   = '&access_token='.$url['access_token'];
        $fields         = '&fields='.$url['fields'];
        $limit          = '&limit=100';
        $after          = '&after='.$url['after'];

        $res['until'] = $access_token.$fields.$limit.$after;

        file_put_contents($this->dirM, $res['until'], LOCK_EX);

        if ( empty($url['access_token']) || empty($url['fields']) || empty($url['limit']) || empty($url['after']) ) 
        {
            file_put_contents($this->dirM, '', LOCK_EX); //clean my txt file that contains my next string
            die('FINE');
        }

    } catch (Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
        echo 'm2Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    } catch (Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
        echo 'm2Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    }
}
```